# Streaming an object (as JSON) over the network in C#

Tags: c#, json, stream, network-programming

I try to send an object of a specific class via the network in C# using the DataContractJsonSerializer class. Unfortunately the data seems not to be received by the recipient.
The following demo program shows the effect. The demo program works in general, but the object is only received by the receiver when the sender shuts down the socket.
What can I do when I want the socket to remain open for sending more data after a while?

```
THE CLASS TO BE TRANSMITTED:

[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime datetime;

    [DataMember]
    public string contents;

    public Message()
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        contents = "Hello World";
    }

    public void WriteJson(Stream stream)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Message));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, this);
    }

    public static Message ReadJson(Stream stream)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Message));
        return (Message)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteJson(stream);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress adr = IPAddress.Loopback;
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(adr, 4711);
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect ...");
                    clientSocket.Connect(ep);
                    NetworkStream clientSocketStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);

                    //receive data
                    Message m = Message.ReadJson(clientSocketStream);
                    Console.WriteLine(m);
                    clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    clientSocket.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

SERVER CODE:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int PORT = 4711;

            IPAddress adr = IPAddress.Any;
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(adr, PORT);
            Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(ep);
            serverSocket.Listen(20);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection request on port {0} ...", PORT);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                NetworkStream clientSocketStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);

                Console.WriteLine("Hello is sent to:  " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint);
                Message m = new Message();
                m.WriteJson(clientSocketStream);
                //clientSocketStream.Flush();

                Console.Write("Wait for key input ...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                //Message is received at the client only when the follwing code is execured
                clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                clientSocket.Close();
            }
            serverSocket.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Where did you find this code?  This kind was used 30 years ago

Comment: @Serge so that code stems from before you started coding? Or do you recognize your own early work? ;)

Comment: @rene I wrote my first computer program for money in 1977. Your father was not born yet.